# How to show thumbnail from a folder using javascript in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have uploaded some images using uploadify and saving the original file in "uploads" folder and thumbnails in "uploads\thumbs" folder now what I need is I have a div element on the main.aspx page where I need to show thumbnail image.After clicking the thumbnail I need to give a lightbox effect to it.

1.I have done this way but this is showing me the original image instead of thumbnail.So how do I point to my thumbnail.

2.When Using Lightbox effect how do I manage my two Imagess with the below code.

This is my Handler code:

```
Public Class UploadVB : Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim postedFile As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files("Filedata")

        Dim savepath As String = ""
        Dim tempPath As String = ""
        tempPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FolderPath")
        savepath = context.Server.MapPath(tempPath)
        Dim filename As String = postedFile.FileName
        If Not Directory.Exists(savepath) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath)
        End If
        If Not Directory.Exists(savepath + "\thumbs") Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath +"\thumbs")
        End If


        postedFile.SaveAs((savepath & "\") + filename)
        Dim fullImage As System.Drawing.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap((savepath & "\") + filename)

        Dim newWidth As Integer = 200
        Dim newHeight As Integer = 200

        Dim temp As New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
        Dim newImage As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(temp)
        newImage.DrawImage(fullImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
        temp.Save((savepath +"\thumbs"  & "\") + "t_" + filename)

        context.Response.Write((tempPath & "/") + filename)
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200



    End Sub
```

Here is my java script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(
function () {
    $("#Inputfile").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
        'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
        'script': 'UploadVB.ashx',
        'folder': 'uploads',
        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'queueSizeLimit':9999,
        'simUploadLimit': 2,
        'sizeLimit': 4000000,
        'multi': true,
        'auto': true,
        'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
            $("#Original").append('<img src="' + response + '"/>')

        },

        'onError': function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
            alert(errorObj.type + ' Error: ' + errorObj.info);
        }


    });
}
);
```

Here is what I need to show the Images:

```
<div id="Original">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
context.Response.Write((tempPath & "/") + filename)
```

you are referring to the main folder try something like:

```
context.Response.Write((tempPath & "/thumbs/") + filename)
```

As far as the light box effect, you can use some jQuery Plugin like [jQuery Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

You can also create image tag in your handler and send it in response, if the plugin needs the path of both files. Then you can append the complete response to "Original" div.

**Edit:**

Instead of writing:

```
context.Response.Write((tempPath & "/thumbs/") + filename)
```

You can write:

```
context.Response.Write("<a href='"+(tempPath & "/") + filename+"'><img src='"+(tempPath & "/thumbs/") + filename +"'/></a>")
```

and in your script:

```
$("#Original").append(response)
```

It will link your thumbnail to your image. Finally, You'll need to use Lightbox plugin can call its method

```
$("#Original a").lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
```

which will create the lightbox effect.

Comment: I have another small question regarding this after doing this now I am abl to show the thumbnail but how do I link with the main Image using the above script.

Comment: you can use JQuery lightbox plugin as I already mentioned. After adding the script to your project and page, you need to call the method: $('#Original a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});

Comment: you can see the examples from the plugin site.

Comment: Not that as the context.write is now context.Response.Write((tempPath & "/thumbs/") + filename) and in the javascript code we mentioned as $("#thumbnail").append('<img src="' + response + '"/>') so it only shows thumbnail so from this how do I link to view the original image actually I have shown below my DIV element there I am showing the Image.

Comment: How do I write the <img src="" + response +"/> for the original Image and how do I link up with the thumbnail Image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make response like `pathToFile;pathToThumb` and with JavaScript `split()` you can put correct path in correct place.

**EDIT**

```
  context.Response.Write((tempPath & "/") + filename)
```

in this line you should add path to thumb, ie.

```
  context.Response.Write((tempPath & "/") + filename + ";" + savepath +"\thumbs"  & "\" + "t_" + filename);
```

then, when you get that in javascript you need to do:

```
var paths = response.split(";");

//   paths[0]; path to file
//   paths[1]; path to thumb
```

So these may be used with lightbox or anything else.

... sorry, I'm more c# than vb...

Comment: First thanks for your reply actually I don't know much abt javascript Can you explain me in detail or point to any other link so that I can try it out.

Comment: How do I write the <img src="" + response +"/> for the original Image and how do I link up with the thumbnail Image.

Comment: As I am showing up like this is it the correct way?$("#Enlarge").html(document.write('<IMG SRC="paths[0]">'));

Comment: No, with jquery: `$("#Enlarge").append("<img src='" + paths[0] +"' alt=''>")`